# Hide the menu of the widget

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been trying to hide the widget menu for some time.
The mobile view menu appears.
Any suggestions?

i tried the following code. I only have the widget id.
my css.

```
  .widget_p #eo-footer{ display: none !important; }
```

and it isnt work. thanks!

Comment: Try clearing your cache. It may be because of that. Try to view it in incognito mode and the changes may appear.

Comment: Also resize your screen on desktop to ensure they don’t add classes or remove for the mobile layout